# Can we embed user defined images to the existing image in android application?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to modify the existing image by adding additional tags or logos or pictures in android. Can we do customize an existing image technically ?

Thanks & Regards,
Serenity.

Comment: You are asking if it is possible to edit an image in Android?

Comment: yes, I would like to customize an image by adding logos to the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with use of [canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class in android

---

You can see an exa. [here.](http://www.anddev.org/the_pizza_timer_-_threading-drawing_on_canvas-t126.html)